# Recovery of files + Ubuntu Installation

Tags: testdisk

I used the option, "Install in the Free Space". I intended that as I have freed-up 30GB from my 500 GB Partition (unallocated), Ubuntu would be installed there.

But Ubuntu got installed on the entire disk and just shows Windows 7 as a boot entry.

I am now trying to recover through test disk my important files. Though the test disk identified the drive name before installing Ubuntu, it is showing Linux while verifying cyclinders. I am really nervous as just 5% was scanned in 40 Minutes.

Could you guide me whether the process is correct for data recovery and is there a way to recover my Windows Partition.

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS was easily installed on Free Space without affecting Windows. But Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is creating havoc

Yours
VN

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: you should be more careful next time before *clicking* **next** read closer what it's gonna do.